Good book/video on Mahanyasam
Are there any good book available in Sanskrit/English/Malayalam on Mahanyasam with proper intonations as well?
I am aware of one book in Malayalam by RS Vadyar publications. But it doesnt have intonations
I am also looking for some guideline on the actions (touching respective body parts along with the mantra) as well. So a good video guide is also welcome
